# How to split a string with comma separated values from table into 2 text fields?

Tags: java, string, delimiter

I have a table as seen below:

[image: tabel]

I have one `JTextField` which is the left one, and `JDateChooser` which is the right next to the text field.

[image]

How to retrieve the TTL column value and set them into 2 text fields which the first value before comma should be in first text field, and the second value after comma should be in date chooser?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check this [page](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jdbc/basics/processingsqlstatements.html) in order to do the query to your DB. Your query should be something like the following example:

```
SELECT * 
FROM YOUR_DB_NAME
WHERE NIK=?
```

If you prefer to reduce the volume of data returned from the DB you may choose select only the TTL column. 
After this, split the value of `TTL` column using `split` method

```
String str = "bulan,10-11-2017";
String[] parts = str.split(",");
```

Split method will return an array containing different parts of the original `String` that were split based on the delimiter that was passed into `split()` method.

**Example**

For example you queried the database and the `resultset` contains the data returned from the database.

You then need to get the value of the `TTL` column from the `resultset` and save it some `String` type variable

```
String str = rs.getString("TTL");
```

Now use split method on this `str` variable

```
 str = "bulan,10-11-2017";
 String[] parts = str.split(",");
```

For help with how to query the database, see the link provided above

Comment: where should i put the :

`String str = "bulan,10-11-2017";`
`String[] parts = str.split(",");`

because i couldnt put them inside **resultset**

@Yousaf

Comment: you need to call the `split` function after you have received the data from the database. get the value of `TTL` column from `resultset` and then call `split` method on the variable that contains value of `TTL` column

Comment: can you give me the example code mr @Yousaf , im lil bit confuse here